# How to fix PHP error from file ApplicationError.php for sending emails

Tags: php, google-app-engine, email

I'm trying to send an email using PHP from Google App Engine.  To send an email, `Require Once` must include the php file `Message.php`:  See:  [Code example here at Google](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/#PHP_Sending_mail)

```
require_once 'google\appengine\api\mail\Message.php';
```

The `Message.php` file includes:

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail/BaseMessage.php';
```

The `BaseMessage.php` file in turn requires three other PHP files:

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail_service_pb.php';
require_once 'google/appengine/runtime/ApiProxy.php';
require_once 'google/appengine/runtime/ApplicationError.php';
```

So, to recap, `Message.php` requires `BaseMessage.php` and `BaseMessage.php` requires 3 more php files.

Everything works fine until that last PHP file that is required:

```
require_once 'google/appengine/runtime/ApplicationError.php';
```

Then a fatal error happens:

```
Fatal error: Class 'google\appengine\runtime\Error' not found in
C:\Users\UserName\Dropbox\ApplicationName\google\appengine\runtime\
ApplicationError.php on line 22
```

This is line 22:

```
class ApplicationError extends Error {
```

This is code that is provided by Google:  [the latest PHP SDK for App Engine](http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/GoogleAppEngine-1.8.9.msi)

It's not code that I wrote.  The path to the required files seems to be working, or else I'd get an error msg on the first required file.  I've tested `require_once` lines of code that reference other PHP files in the same directories with no errors.  So the issue isn't a problem with the relative path or the PHP.ini file.

My PHP version is `Current PHP version: 5.4.22`
Windows 7
XAMPP with Netbeans, Apache

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: the latest sdk has autoloading - you should not need to use require/include for any of the SDK functions.

Comment: The example code from Google uses `require`.  I'm open to using any code I can get to work.  So if anyone can point me to code, and a configuration that works I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the PHP email code to work.  I still don't know what the exact problem was to begin with, but it must have something to do with how my Netbeans IDE is currently configured to PHP.  The Google App Engine SDK has PHP built into it's installation, but I wasn't running my app from the Google App Engine Launcher.   When I ran my app directly from the Google App Engine Launcher, the code worked.  I'm guessing that the Netbeans version of PHP was a little different than the Google App Engine SDK version of PHP.   And that caused an error in one of the files.  In any case, I got the PHP code that sends a email to work.  So, the code will run.  That tells me that my configuration to PHP in Netbeans probably isn't the same as the configuration to PHP in the version of PHP in the Google App Engine SDK.  I might try tweaking the PHP.ini file in netbeans to see if I can link directly to the Google App Engine SDK verion of PHP.